# How to set Button's background color Programatically >= API 26?

Tags: android, button, background-color

My App run correctly on Android 4.0, while when run on 8.0, the Button's background color won't changed, I tried :

```
 btnThree.setBackground(getResources().getColor(color.btnThreeColor));
 btnThree.setBackgroundColor(btnThreeColor);
 btnThree.setBackgroundResource(btnThreeColor);
```

they all didn't work. How to set background color?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something only for ">=26", I think you can add this condition.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=26){
   //set button's background
}
```

Also you can check more details at [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).

Comment: I want it run both on ANDROID 4.0 and 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:
btnThree.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(btnThreeColor));

you should input in getColor():
R.color.btnThreeColor, and the Android Studio would transfer it into:btnThreeColor.